# New to MacOS and trying to replicate a few things that I already do using Autohotkey on windows

Tags: macos, macros, automation, autohotkey

Below is my Autohotkey script that automatically copies the text of any questions that I ask on the websites for ChatGPT, Gemini, and Claude (I have them installed as chrome apps) by detecting the service's name in the window title. Here's what my script looks like:

```
Enter::
WinGetTitle, currentWindowTitle, A ; Get the title of the active window
    if (InStr(currentWindowTitle, "ChatGPT")) {
        Send, ^a
        Sleep, 100
        Send, ^c
        Sleep, 100
        Send, {Enter}
    } else if (InStr(currentWindowTitle, "Gemini")) {
        Send, ^a
        Sleep, 100
        Send, ^c
        Sleep, 100
        Send, {Enter}
    } else if (InStr(currentWindowTitle, "Claude")) {
        Send, ^a
        Sleep, 100
        Send, ^c
        Sleep, 100
        Send, {Enter}
    }
    else
    send, {Enter}
return
```

I have  tried  Karabiner-Elements but was not able to do it.

Comment: Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).